# Proof symmetry after 2D-convolution with $1/\lvert \mathbf x\rvert$ implies 2D-symmetry

Tags: convolution, image-processing

Let be two 2D functions $f(x,y)\geq 0 \ \forall (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ and $g(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

I have, furthermore,
$$\int_{\mathbb R^2} f(t_1,t_2)g(x-t_1,y-t_2)dt_1dt_2=\int_{\mathbb R^2} f(-t_1,-t_2)g(x-t_1,y-t_2)dt_1dt_2,$$
which are two convolution products.

Can I prove that $f(t_1,t_2)=f(-t_1,-t_2), \ \forall (t_1,t_2)\in \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Homework question with no mention of attempts to solve.

Comment: Did you try assuming f(x)!=f(-x) for a given x, then compute your convolution sums and show they are not equal?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the result that you wish to prove is in fact true?  From equality of integrals to equality of integrands is a _long_ step.